# In which shader should i put technique11 section

Tags: visual-studio-2013, vertex-shader, pixel-shader

In VS 2010 i used to have one shader file for VS and PS and at the end of the file i had some techniques declared.

With VS 2013 i forced to have separate files for VS and PS. Where should i put techniques section? It needs to see both procedures i think.

My techniques were like that:

```
technique11 TexNo
{
    pass P0
    {
        SetVertexShader( CompileShader( vs_5_0, VS() ) );
        SetGeometryShader( NULL );
        SetPixelShader( CompileShader( ps_5_0, PS(false) ) );
    }
}

technique11 TexYes
{
    pass P0
    {
        SetVertexShader( CompileShader( vs_5_0, VS() ) );
        SetGeometryShader( NULL );
        SetPixelShader( CompileShader( ps_5_0, PS(true) ) );
    }
}
```